# How can I replicate this cy.intercept in Playwright?

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress, playwright

I am looking to migrate my test suite from Cypress to Playwright. I have hit a hurdle as I came to API requests.

Within my test suite, I want to wait for network request to be completed and return a 200 response, before moving onto the next action.

My issue is the network request url contains a dynamic value, previously in Cypress I have '*' in place as a wildcard, what is the alternative within Playwright?

I have the following cy.intercept in my code:

```
cy.intercept('GET',`${apiUrl}/employee/*/information`).as('GETemployeeInformation');
```

I call this intercept with cy.wait in my test suite before proceeding with the test steps, I have tried to replicate this in Playwright with the following:

```
async isSignedIn() {
    await this.page.waitForResponse(response => response.url().includes("/employee/*/information") && response.status() === 200);
  }
```

Comment: It supports regex, so this will work: response.url().match(/\/employee\/.*\/information/)

Answer (score 8):

The example given here [Network events](https://playwright.dev/docs/network#network-events) seems to be pretty close to the Cypress pattern. There may be better patterns in Playwright, but if you are converting from Cypress to Playwright I'd try this.

```js
// Use a glob URL pattern. Note no await.
const responsePromise = page.waitForResponse('**/api/fetch_data');
await page.getByText('Update').click();
const response = await responsePromise;
```

Since the glob pattern is allowed in Playwright, I'm wondering if your issue comes from using `response.url()` to make the match. In Cypress the match is against `request.url` not `response.url`.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like:

```
// Start waiting for response with given url before action (click)
  const [response] = await Promise.all([
    page.waitForResponse('https://some.example.com/myData.json'),
    page.locator(SUBMIT_BUTTON).click(),
  ]);
  expect(response.status()).toBe(200);
});
```